# End of AngularJS, Build (Minify, concat,...)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, gulp

I ended my Angular JS app... 
and now what?

I have a app with 10 scripts src in index.html, 6 ng includes,... 
All this are http requests, and have a relative size...

There are some particular way or command for "compile/build/generate/deploy" end app code? with all included, minified,...

Or I must do this with grunt/gulp :(?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="Bit2Card" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="Bit2Card" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="Bit2Card" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="Bit2Card" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Generate a credit card on fly with Bitcoins">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="browsehappy">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
    </p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div id="app" ng-controller="appController" class="{{viewBack ? 'viewBack' : ''}}">

        <ng-include src="'partials/overlays/load.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'partials/overlays/error.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'partials/overlays/terms.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'partials/overlays/qr.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'partials/overlays/payout.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'partials/overlays/restart.html'"></ng-include>

        <div id="flip">
            <div id="frontCard">
                <ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></ng-include>
                <div id="panels">
                    <div id="select" class="panel{{panel === 1 ? ' visible' : ''}}" ng-include="'partials/panels/select.html'"></div>
                    <div id="pay" class="panel{{panel === 2 ? ' visible' : ''}}" ng-include="'partials/panels/pay.html'"></div>
                    <div id="get" class="panel{{panel === 3 ? ' visible' : ''}}" ng-include="'partials/panels/get.html'"></div>
                </div>
                <ng-include src="'partials/footer.html'"></ng-include>
            </div>
            <div id="backCard" ng-include="'partials/backside.html'"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--
    In production use:
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ng-clip/dest/ng-clip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/qrcode/lib/qrcode.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-qr/angular-qr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lin2a.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "end" do you mean you finished your project?

Comment: You have to use grunt/gulp as you suggested. [Here is a neat Gruntfile.js that shows how to build your app](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: Technically you don't _have_ to use gulp/grunt, but it's by far the easiest solution. You can include libraries and write your own build scripts, that's what we had to do before (in ancient times)

Comment: thanks, I'm sad because all that I need is explicitly in the index file. Will must to be some tool for this that all we need to do at end of project or when we want deploy a version. Reading index file for example or some standar like RequireJS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-html-replace.  It will read through that html for you and insert a new script tag in there that points to a bundled version of all those deps.